# C#: Not receiving from GSM device

Tags: c#, serial-port, gsm, gprs

I've coded a little program to read/send SMS messages using a GSM device. My code worked fine on one kind of device. Today I am using a different device and my program can't receive from it (although it can send to it just fine). The device works just fine with the same configs under puTTY.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Variables.sp.PortName = "COM1";
        Variables.sp.BaudRate = 9600;
        Variables.sp.DataBits = 8;
        Variables.sp.Parity = Parity.None;
        Variables.sp.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        Variables.sp.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

        try
        {
            Variables.sp.Open();
            Variables.sp.WriteLine("AT\r");
            //Variables.sp.WriteLine("AT+CMGF=1\r");
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Can't open COM1. Quit and try again.");
        }
    }

    private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        string indata = sp.ReadExisting();

        MessageBox.Show(indata);
    }
```

Any idea why it would work fine on one device and not the other? While I'm typing the same commands under puTTY and they both work the same?

Comment: The event handler should not be static. This, however, doesn't solve your problems, probably.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. No my problem is the same. More worrying is that my teacher's code doesn't even work for this device. However I can double confirm that the device works absolutely fine with the standard commands under puTTY, I just sent myself an SMS.

Comment: Are you sure the baud rate and other COM port settings are the same? And what about using `AT\r\n` instead of just `\r`?

Comment: Yes: COM1, baud=9600, data bits = 8, stop bits = 1, parity = none
under puTTY, the same.
Tried with \r\n as well, no luck.
Makes no sens!!!

Comment: I was told I don't need to set Flow Control under C# because it would be XON/XOFF by default, is this true? Can I check what the flow control is set to?

Comment: See `Handshake` property.

Comment: Maybe send and receive an SMS manually from each device, using Hyperterminal and AT commands, to try and see any differences between the devices?